# permission 403 error

Tags: http-status-code-403, virtualhost, permissions

I switched from opensuse yesterday and i'm trying to configure the personal pc. In opensuse was pretty easy because i only needed to use the yast.

Now:
I've got 403 error

```
Forbidden 

You dont have permission to access / on this server. 

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at ros Port 80
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/ros

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80> 
        ServerAdmin admin@ros 
        ServerName ros 
    ServerAlias ros 
        DocumentRoot /home/daniel/Public/ros       
        <Directory /home/daniel/Public/ros/> 
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
                AllowOverride All 
                Order allow,deny 
                allow from all 
        </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

The /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.2    ros www.ros
```

Also in /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Thu Jun 24 11:32:20 2010] [crit] [client 127.0.0.2] (13)Permission denied: /home/daniel/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

I have chown the /home/daniel/Public/ros folder with the following command

```
chown -R daniel:www-data /home/daniel/Public/ros
```

also tried **www-data:www-data** in chown. But I don't see why it says permission denied /home/daniel/.htaccess/ 
Thank you !

Comment: Please ls -l /home/daniel/.htaccess and post the result.

Comment: daniel@daniel-dev:~$ ls -l /home/daniel/.htaccess
ls: cannot access /home/daniel/.htaccess: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your home directory is probably 700. Apache just needs +x to get into the directory so we can just do this

```
chmod +x /home/daniel
```

As long as /home/daniel/Public/ros is 755 you should be good to go.